# Disable or hide a button when an object is empty Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I disable a button once the user was able to send a request. I used the logic of checking if an object in empty or has value in the controller and if the object is empty the user can submit a request otherwise the button will be hidden or disabled.

Object in the Controller

```
@c_req = Notification.where("message LIKE ?", "%{friend}%")
```

View

```
<%= form_for :friend, url: friends_path, method: :post do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :message, :value => "Accepted your friend request" %>
<%= f.hidden_field :date, :value => @date %>
<%= f.submit 'Submit', :disabled => @c_req.present? %>
<% end %>
```

I used `:disabled => @c_req.present?` to check if it has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `disabled` attribute is added in any `input` field then it will be disabled either it is `disabled = false`.

You want to `enable` button if `object` is empty.

```
<%= form_for :friend, url: friends_path, method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :message, value: "Accepted your friend request" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :date, value: @date %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit',class: "submit_btn" %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    <% unless @c_req.empty? %>
      $(".submit_btn").attr('disabled', true)
    <% end %>

  })
</script>
```

Above js code runs when page is loading, if the `@c_req` is `empty` then your `submit` button is `enable` else `disable`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `<%= f.submit 'Submit', :disabled => @c_req.present? %>` with `<%= f.submit 'Submit', :disabled => !@c_req.present? %>`

Answer (score 0):

`#present?` is used to check if the item is there. Disabling has to happen if the item is not there. For that we have `#empty?`

Please don't use things like `c_req`, be a little descriptive in variable names. Also follow a code style, some thing like [this](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)...

Update to your code...

```
<%= form_for :friend, url: friends_path, method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :message, value: "Accepted your friend request" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :date, value: @date %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit', disabled: @c_req.empty? %>
<% end %>
```

If you are hiding it... Use a similar query to decide not to show the button or hide the button from css.

Ex:

```
<%= f.submit 'Submit', class: ('hidden' if @c_req.empty?) %>
```

I guess you get the idea!

Answer (score 0):

You have twisted the logic. You want to disable the button if it does NOT exist.

I'd try changing to `.any?` or `.empty?`

And be nice you your future self and name the variable better.